# how to show records related to a certain user in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, user-permissions

I want to create a way for users to only be able to edit/add objects (Company objects) related with the logged in user.

Currently all logged in users are able to edit all Companys even when I create permissions to:

```
Company | Can Add Company
Company | Can Change Company
```

What can I add to the Admin.py to constrain a user to be able to to edit/add objects (Company objects) related with the logged in user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [`ModelAdmin.get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) can help. You can use it to perform checks on the `request.user` object.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)
```